# pytorch custom loss function on minimizing the angle between vectors

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, loss-function

The goal is to minimize the angle between the actual and predicted vectors in a neural network setting. Can someone please check if the following execution is correct?

```
criterion = nn.CosineSimilarity() 
loss = torch.mean(torch.abs(criterion(actual_vectors,predicted_vectors)))

#back-propagation on the above *loss* will try cos(angle) = 0. But I want angle between the vectors to be 0 or cos(angle) = 1.

loss = 1 - loss

#To me, the above does not seem right. Isn't back-propagation on the above 'loss' similar to minimizing the negative of 'loss' from line 2?
#Does '1' have no role to play here when back-propagation is applied?

loss.backward()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically that makes sense. The goal of back-propagation is to minimize the loss. If the loss is `1 - cos(A)` (where A is the angle difference between the two) then that is equivalent to saying that the goal is to maximize `cos(A)`, which in turn is equivalent to minimizing the Angle between the two vectors.

A simple example would be the goal of minimizing `X^2 + 4` the answer to that optimization problem is the same as the answer to the goal of maximizing `-(X^2 + 4)`. Sticking a minus on the whole equation and swapping min with max would make the statements equivalent. So if you have a function you want to MAXIMIZE and your optimization model can only MINIMIZE then just slap a minus sign on your function and call it a day.

Another question you might ask is "what is significant about the 1? Could we have just said `loss = -loss`" and the answer is... it depends. Theoretically yes that is equivalent and the one doesn't play a role in the backward propagation (since it disappears with the derivative). However, once we start talking about actual optimization with numerical errors and complicated optimizers/update rules then the constant 1 might play a role.

Another reason to have the 1 is so that your loss is nicely defined between 0 and 1 which is a nice property to have.

So yes, minimizing the loss of `1 - cos(A)` through back-propagation is equivalent to minimizing the angle between the vectors.

Comment: That's helpful! Also, "Another question you might ask is "what is significant about the 1?" - this is another question I actually had in mind. Thanks for your opinion on that.

Comment: Hi @AjayA  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @A Kareem, sure. Will wait one or two days to hear, if any, from others and make sure to accept an answer